# How can I get PAM to check a condition only on initial login?

Tags: pam

Similar to [Configure pam_mount to only prompt at initial login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416919/274431), but the recommended answer does not work on RHEL 9 (and apparently didn't work for the person who originally asked the question).

I need to set up DUO two-factor authentication on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9. Following the [instructions](https://duo.com/docs/duounix) on the vendor's website results in a setup that requires answering a 2FA challenge every time the user enters a password, e.g. for `sudo`. I would like to modify this setup to prompt for a 2FA challenge only on the initial login.

I added the following to /etc/authselect/password-auth after the line containing `pam_unix.so`:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = systemd-user quiet
auth    sufficient                    pam_duo.so
```

The pam_succeed_if condition was suggested both on the linked question and on the Arch wiki (itself linked in that question). However, the pam_succeed_if condition fails every time, and now every time the system is unlocked, DUO prompts for 2FA. How can I reliably skip DUO if the user has already logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using information from a few other answers. First, it's not possible to differentiate between login and unlocking using only PAM modules, at least on GNOME, as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473813/274431). The other answers to that question suggest using `pam_script` as a workaround, but I wasn't crazy about using somebody's github project in my PAM stack. Fortunately, the built-in `pam_exec` will do the same job.

First, modify the script from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538032/274431) for use with `pam_exec`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

SESSION_ID=$(loginctl session-status | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)

if [ -z "$SESSION_ID" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
if ! loginctl show-session "$SESSION_ID" | grep '^LockedHint=yes$' > /dev/null; then
    exit 1
fi

# Current session is locked, return success
exit 0
```

Save it in `/etc/pam.d/is-current-session-locked` or wherever you want, as long as the path passed to `pam_exec` is modified accordingly. Be sure to make the script executable.

The use of the command stored in `SESSION_ID` rather than `XDG_SESSION_ID` is because GNOME (at least on RHEL 9) doesn't store anything to `XDG_SESSION_ID`. The return values are changed to exit values because `pam_exec` checks the exit value of a command, and the exit values themselves are dependent on what your PAM stack logic is.

Next, I added the following line before the line for `pam_duo.so`:

```
auth    sufficient    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam.d/is-current-session-locked/pam_script_auth.sh
```

Since `pam_duo` is also sufficient, nothing after it is processed anyway.

And of course, as mentioned in the other answer, it's a good idea to be logged in and have a root shell in another session. I locked myself out a few times while figuring this out, but because I had the root shell open I could just switch to that session and fix the PAM file to be able to unlock the graphical session.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish the 2FA challenge to happen only on initial login, then you must refer to `pam_duo.so` only with the services that handle initial logins.

Out of abundance of caution, you might instead wish to explicitly list the services that *are* allowed to skip the 2FA, so you won't accidentally leave a 2FA-free "hole" on a service you did not realize needs 2FA after all.

The line

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = systemd-user quiet
```

means: "If the condition "service = systemd-user" matches, skip the next `auth` configuration line, otherwise proceed as if this line did not exist at all."

To provide a similar skip for two services (e.g. `systemd-user` and `sudo`), you could do this:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = sudo quiet
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = systemd-user quiet
auth    sufficient                    pam_duo.so
```

If the first line matches, we already know the service requesting authentication was `sudo`, so we don't have to check if it was `systemd-user`. So we skip two lines: the `systemd-user` check and the `pam_duo.so` authentication module.

If you want to allow 2FA-less `su` also (just as an example), you would add a third line:

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = su quiet
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = sudo quiet
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so service = systemd-user quiet
auth    sufficient                    pam_duo.so
```

And so on.

As always, when modifying PAM configuration, it is wise to **not log out** after you've tested your changes: if you are making the change over a SSH connection, open a second SSH connection for testing instead of logging out of the first one. If you are making the change locally, open a second terminal window and become root in there, or switch to a different virtual console and login in text mode likewise.  You'll want a session that already is logged in with full root privileges ready to undo your changes in case it turns out you made a critical mistake.

On production systems, I personally would first log in a *second* SSH connection and switch it to root before making PAM changes, just to guard against accidental "fingers-faster-than-brain" logouts.

Comment: Re: "you must refer to pam_duo.so only with the services that handle initial logins" does this mean the configuration needs to be done in a different PAM file than `/etc/authselect/password-auth`? Otherwise I don't see how this is substantially different from what I've already attempted.